# Session token is not appending for axios interceptor on login

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Hi i need to append sessiontoken for services request after login, for successfull login  i am using 
this.props.history.replace('/cards') and it is redirecting to cards page but initially sessiontoken is not adding to header, once i refresh the page sessiotoken is adding to request header:
in index.js i am using axios interceptor:

```
const sessionToken = localStorage.getItem("sessionToken");
  axios.interceptors.request.use(
            request => {
              console.log("inside index.js");
              if (sessionToken) {
                request.headers.sessionToken = sessionToken;
              }
              return request;
            },
            error => {
              console.log(error);
              return Promise.reject(error);
            }
          );
```

and in cards file:

```
const res = await axios.get(
      "url"
    );
```

in login

```
 localStorage.setItem('accountInfo',JSON.stringify(response.data.account));
          localStorage.setItem('sessionToken',response.data.sessionToken);
          //this.props.history.replace('/cards')
          this.props.history.push('/cards');
```

i have tried both history.push and history.replace both
Where is the problem any help.